# Using getAssets outside an activity

Tags: android

I try to parse a file in my DatabaseHandler class but Eclipse say:

> The method getAssets() is undefined for the type DatabaseHandler

This is the code:

```
 public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 15;

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, "rettinfo", null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("Create: ", "Creating antidotlist");
        String CREATE_ANTIDOT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE antidots (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY antidot TEXT, dos TEXT)";
        Log.d("Create: ", CREATE_ANTIDOT_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ANTIDOT_TABLE);

        InputStream antidots = getAssets().open("antidot/antidots");
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(antidots);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(input,2*1024);
        String line;
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] point_t = line.split(",");
        }
        antidots.close();
    }

}
```

**Update for Tim**

This is how eclipse dont make any errors

```
int i = 0;
InputStream antidots;
    try {
        antidots = mCtx.getAssets().open("antidot/antidots");
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(antidots);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(input,2*1024);
        String line;
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            i++;
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            String[] antidot = line.split("#");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(antidot[0]);
            values.put("id", id);
            values.put("antidot", antidot[1]);
            values.put("dos", antidot[2]);  
            db.insert("antidots", null, values);                     
        }
        antidots.close();           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: yes the try catch is normal. Anytime you are dealing with file io it will make you wrap the code in try/catch. It does this because there lots of common ways that file i/o operations can fail. And without the try/catch your program will simply crash in the event that there is an issue with the i/o

Comment: Also note that the file i/o try catch is due to a java convention, and is not specific to eclipse.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Store a reference to the `Context` that you get from the constructor then call getAssets() on that reference.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 15;
    private Context mCtx; //<-- declare a Context reference
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, "rettinfo", null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mCtx = context; //<-- fill it with the Context you are passed
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("Create: ", "Creating antidotlist");
        String CREATE_ANTIDOT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE antidots (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY antidot TEXT, dos TEXT)";
        Log.d("Create: ", CREATE_ANTIDOT_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ANTIDOT_TABLE);

        InputStream antidots = mCtx.getAssets().open("antidot/antidots"); //<-- call getAssets on your Context object.
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(antidots);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(input,2*1024);
        String line;
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] point_t = line.split(",");
        }
        antidots.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Post, is it normal that Eclipse want to surround with try/catch?

Comment: It wants to surround which lines?